# State is not updating with correct information

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hello I am trying to update the vale of my state in React but I don't know why it always goes to the option where selectedUser is not defined. I tried putting everything inside an if-else but I got the same results, the strange thing is that when I wrote something in the console it went inside my conditional but it took the empty values instead.

```
const [inputFieldState, setInputFieldState] = useState(InputFields(selectedUser));

function InputFields(selectedUser: any) {

  return selectedUser
    ? selectedUser
    : {
        email: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        customerId: "",
        id: "",
        role: ""
      };
}
```

selectedUser is a fake value for now

```
return {
    firstName: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    lastName: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    customerId: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    id: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    role: names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)],
    email: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
  };
```

when I do a console log of the selected user I get

```
{firstName: "x-wing", lastName: "Winnebago", customerId: "y-wing", id: "TIE-fighter", role: "Anakin", …}
customerId: "y-wing"
email: 2
firstName: "x-wing"
id: "TIE-fighter"
lastName: "Winnebago"
role: "Anakin"
```

Comment: where are you getting value of selectedUser?

Comment: selectedUser is s fake value that I created

Comment: return {
    firstName: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    lastName: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    customerId: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    id: planes[Math.floor(Math.random() * planes.length)],
    role: names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)],
    email: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5)
  };

Comment: why is there a return for selectedUser ?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, `selectedUser` is a function

```
const [inputFieldState, setInputFieldState] = useState(InputFields(selectedUser()));

function InputFields(user: any) { // just changed the name to avoid potential confusion
  return user
    ? user
    : {
        email: "",
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        customerId: "",
        id: "",
        role: ""
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change  useState(InputFields(selectedUser)) to

```
useState(() => InputFields(selectedUser))
```

so that it will not use the Initial state in every render